# How to let a user input a function

Tags: scilab

I know that the input syntax in scilab looks like this:

```
result = input ("Enter your number: ")
```

My problem is, how can I enter a function like cos(x) + sin(x) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the user enter a string (parameter "s" of the `input` command), and use this string in `eval` command for evaluation. Example:

```
fstr = input("Enter a function of x: ", "s")
x = input("What is the value of x: ")
y = eval(fstr) 
disp("The value of function is " + string(y))
```

The string evaluation can be wrapped as a Scilab function, too:

```
fstr = input("Enter a function of x: ", "s")
function y = f(x)
    y=eval(fstr)
endfunction

t = linspace(0, 2)
plot(t, f(t))
```

Comment: Sir. How about after I asked him the function. I want to plot that function. How can I do that? Or how can I make that string to become a real function, so that I can manipulate it and do whatever I want from the entered function by the user.

Comment: It doesn't seems to work with polynomial functions tho. Like e.g 3x+1

Comment: @AndréHeringer Works fine with 3*x+1. When computers are involved, multiplication sign is not normally omitted.